# Characteristic function of set difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $A,B$ are subsets of set $X$. Is it true to suppose that $$\chi_{A-B}=|\chi_A-\chi_B|$$

Comment: Have you tried this out with some simple examples of 1 and 2 point sets?

Comment: @LeeMosher, Yes I have proved it in general case

Comment: @LeeMosher, So am I correct?

Comment: No, you are not, as the posted answer shows. Which is why I asked if you had tried it out with some simple examples.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming these are the standard definitions, i.e. $A-B=\{x\mid x\in A, x\notin B\}$ and $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$, $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$, then no.
E.g. if $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$, then $\chi_{A-B}=\chi_A$ as a function,
since $A-B=A$. However, $|\chi_A-\chi_B|=\chi_{A\cup B}$, since it evaluates to
$|1-0|=1$ on $x=1$ and $|0-1|=1$ on $x=2$.

What would be correct is the symmetric difference: if $A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$, then $\chi_{A\Delta B}=|\chi_A-\chi_B|$. (This is easy to see from the fact that the difference is zero precisely when the function values are the same, i.e. the argument $x$ is in both or neither set.)